# Java printf specify variable width

Tags: java, printf

I have this simplified code:

```
System.out.printf("%-*s   Exam Percentage: %4.1f   Final Grade: %c\n", VAR, "fox"+", "+"jim",25.3225, 'C');
```

Which, according to [this](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm) and other resources, should produce a column 'VAR' characters wide to the effect of:

```
 fox, jim   Exam Percentage:  25.3    Final Grade: C
```

It runs through a for loop and VAR is the largest size of the first string.

I reconize the method:

```
System.out.printf("%-"+VAR+"s   Exam Percentage: %4.1f   Final Grade: %c\n", "fox"+", "+"jim",25.3225, 'C');
```

It works, but I am mainly curious. Also, the afore mentioned page mentions 'argsize' an explanation into that may provide some insight.

P.S. I know the the code has literals. Its for simplicity.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. What exactly is your question? :-/

Comment: You don't expect System.out.printf is defined as in your Lava resource? System.out is a java.io.PrintStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format strings for method [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) of a java.io.PrintStream such as System.out are defined as [Java format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). They differ from the documentation you linked which is for something called Lava. In particular the width for a percent-conversion in Java is a number and cannot be replaced by an asterisk (*). In other words, as you noticed, it's not OK to write `%-*s` but it is OK to write `%-20s` or whatever your preferred number is.